# arreglo con datos de una consulta sql

Tags: php

Como puedo obtener el numero de registros ejemplo:

count(id) = 20

necesito un arreglo con valores total=[1,2,3,4---20]

de manera que si tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

x numero de id pueda contarlos independientemente de su valor 
id = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...14]

Comment: Quieres sumar los valores del campo `id_##` o quieres el total de filas que hay en la tabla? No entiendo :/

Comment: ¿Quieres obtener el conjunto de `id_##` al mismo tiempo que obtienes la cantidad de `id_##`?

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer esto:

Consulta

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as RowCounter FROM fooTable;
```

forma de imprimirlo:

```
echo $Result['RowCounter'];
```